# Java code to append numbers to non-english character in file name

Tags: filenames, non-english

I have a list of files whose file name contains non-English characters. It is required to prefix a unique 16 digit number to the names of these files. I have a text file, say "FileMap.txt" which stores the non-English file name and its corresponding 16 digit number. So, I wrote a java code to create a hashmap out of FileMap.txt with key as the file name and value as the corresponding 16 digit number. Then i read the folder to iterate the file names one by one and compare it with the keys of the HashMap. When I did HashMap.containsKey(FileName), it always returns negative. I always get the output printed as No file name found as per the below code

```
        BufferedReader buf_inreader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\APPS\\DATA\\1013013\\FileMap.txt"));
        String strLine = buf_inreader.readLine();
        HashMap<String,String> hmFileNameIDMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        while(strLine != null) {
            stTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(strLine,"\t",false);
            int iIndex=0;
            strID = "";strFileName = "";
            while(stTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                strToken = stTokenizer.nextToken();
                if(iIndex == 0) {
                    strID = strToken;
                }
                if(iIndex == 1) {
                    strFileName = strToken;
                }
                iIndex++;
            }
            if(!"".equals(strFileName)) {
                //System.out.println("strFileName before putting into hashmap " + strFileName);
                hmFileNameIDMap.put(strFileName, strID);
            }
            strLine = buf_inreader.readLine();
        }

        File folderObj = new File("C:\\APPS\\DATA\\INPUT");
        File[] fileList = folderObj.listFiles();
        for(File fileObj:fileList) {
            strFileName = fileObj.getName();
            if(hmFileNameIDMap.containsKey(strFileName)) {
                strNewName = new StringBuilder(hmFileNameIDMap.get(strFileName)).append("_").append(strFileName).toString();
            } else {
                System.out.println("No file name found for " + strFileName);
            }
        }
```

Comment: FileMap.txt contains the following data:  
ä½ å¥½å—.pdf|1234567890123456
æˆ‘ä¸é«˜å…´.pdf|2345678901234567

File names are ä½ å¥½å—.pdf and æˆ‘ä¸é«˜å…´.pdf